# Use lambda through std::function reference, you cannot modify the value in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++17, c++14

The lambda is used by `std::function` reference, but the value in the lambda cannot be changed. I don't know why? I've used references, but still can't achieve that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void myInvoke(const std::function<void()>& fn)
{
    fn();
}

int main()
{
    int i{ 0 };

    // Increments and prints its local copy of @i.
    auto count{ [i]() mutable {
      std::cout << ++i << '\n';
    } };

    myInvoke(count);
    myInvoke(count);
    myInvoke(count);

    return 0;
}
```

Actual results：

```
1
1
1
```

Expected results：

```
1
2
3
```

After I remove the & symbol, the running result has not changed. I think there should be a difference between the two, but I don't know what it is!

Comment: Your `std::function` gets a copy of the lambda instance.

Comment: And you don't capture i by reference, use `auto count{ [&]() { std::cout << ++i << '\n';  } };`

Comment: @PepijnKramer although it will generate the `1 2 3` output, it will be only via changing the `i` in `main`, and I don't think this is what the OP tried to achieve. In the begining I was going in that direction as well, but then thought the OP would like to use the `i` member of the lambda, without affecting `i` of `main`. My answer shows how to do it, as well as the answer by Matt.

Comment: @ZheCi - can you clarify if your intention was to modify the `i` member of the lambda only (without affecting `i` in `main`) ?

Comment: Yes, my purpose is to modify i in lambda, I don't care whether to modify i in main.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You attempt `myInvoke` to accept the function `fn` by reference, but the `count` lambda that you pass is not a `std::function`.
Each time you call `myInvoke` with your lambda, it is converted to a `std::function` by means of creating a **temporary object (a copy)**. That's what `fn` is referencing.
And so `i` will be modified on the **copy** and will not affect your `count` lambda.
This is also why accepting `fn` by value behaves similarly.

One way to handle it is to make `myInvoke` a **function template** where `fn` is a template argument (of type `T &`), so no conversion needs to be done.

**Code example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void myInvoke(T & fn)
{
    fn();
}

int main()
{
    int i{ 0 };

    // Increments and prints its local copy of @i.
    auto count = [i]() mutable {
      std::cout << ++i << '\n';
    };

    myInvoke(count);
    myInvoke(count);
    myInvoke(count);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
```

An alternative way would be to make `count` of type `std::function<void()>` as suggested in the other answer by @Matt.
This will also prevent the creation of temporary copies per call, since the `fn` would be able to bind to it directly.

**Note:**
Another option that was mentioned is to change your lambda to capture `i` by reference instead of by value:

```
//------------vv------------
auto count = [&i]() { ... };
```

This will output `1 2 3` as you expect, but only because all function copies will actually modify the `i` on the stack of `main`.
I thought this is not what you wanted, but rather to increment only the `i` member of the lambda.

Comment: I think you made a very crucial point: lambdas are not std::function

Because lambda is not std::function, when executing parameter passing (const std::function<void()> &fn = lambda), a std::function<void()> will be generated according to lambda to solve the type mismatch The problem

Is my understanding above correct? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @ZheCi Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Declare `count` as `std::function<void()>` and remove the `const` from `myInvoke`'s parameter then it works as expected:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void myInvoke(std::function<void()> &fn) {
  fn();
}

int main() {
  int i{ 0 };

  // Increments and prints its local copy of @i.
  std::function<void()> count{[i]() mutable {
    std::cout << ++i << '\n';
  }};

  myInvoke(count);
  myInvoke(count);
  myInvoke(count);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

@wohlstad's answer gives a good explanation for why you need to declare `count` as `std::function<void()>` instead of `auto` to prevent a temporary object being made when calling `myInvoke()`.

Btw if you replace `[i]` with `[i = 0]` then you don't even need to declare `int i` in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda `count` captures `i` [by copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture). To capture `i` by reference you need

```
auto count{ [&i]() mutable {
  std::cout << ++i << '\n';
} };
```

Test it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e56689f96b24892b).

As noted in a comment, you do not need `mutable` in the lambda when capturing by reference.

Comment: If you capture by reference the mutable is not necessary ;)

Comment: It will work by modifying the `i` in main. I believe the OP wanted to achieve this by modifying the `i` member of the lambda only. This is shown in mine and the other answer.